# Export multiple tables into a Single excel file within the same Excel sheet using data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf

I've created multiple data tables which I want to export in a single Excel file on click of 'Export to Excel'.

I've tried exporting for multiple table but it doesn't work for me as every table has its own Export buttons that will export multiple tables to multiple Excel/PDF files.

I found a code for exporting multiple data tables to a single excel file but for every table a new sheet is being created. But I expect it to be exported in a single excel sheet and same goes for exporting to single PDF file.

Attaching the code to export tables to Excel in multiple excel sheets for reference:

**Script to imported:**

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

      <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <hr/>
      <table id="example2" class="display nowrap" width="100%" data-rowonetitle="My Sheet2" data-sheetname="Summary2">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Big Column Test 1</td>
            <td>Notes 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Test 2</td>
            <td>Notes 2</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
     <hr/> 
    <table id="example3" class="display nowrap" width="100%" data-rowonetitle="My Sheet3" data-sheetname="Summary3">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>TABLE 3</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Comments </th>
            <th>Notes</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Test 1</td>
            <td>Notes 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Test 2</td>
            <td>Notes 2</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
          <table id="example4" class="display nowrap" width="100%" data-rowonetitle="My Sheet4" data-sheetname="Summary4">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>TABLE 4</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Comments </th>
            <th>Notes</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Test 1</td>
            <td>Notes 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Test 2</td>
            <td>Notes 2</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
          <table id="example5" class="display nowrap" width="100%" data-rowonetitle="My Sheet5" data-sheetname="Summary5">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>TABLE 5</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Comments </th>
            <th>Notes</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Test 1</td>
            <td>Notes 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Test 2</td>
            <td>Notes 2</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
          <table id="example6" class="display nowrap" width="100%" data-rowonetitle="My Sheet6" data-sheetname="Summary6">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>TABLE 6</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Comments </th>
            <th>Notes</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Test 1</td>
            <td>Notes 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Test 2</td>
            <td>Notes 2</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>

</div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
<script>

//
// Based on example from:
// http://live.datatables.net/kuyayeto/9/edit
// which in turn is based on example from:
// https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/49457
// modified by me to process additional tables in a loop.
//
$(document).ready( function () {
  
  function getHeaderNames(table) {
    // Gets header names.
    //params:
    //  table: table ID.
    //Returns:
    //  Array of column header names.
    
    var header = $(table).DataTable().columns().header().toArray();

    var names = [];
    header.forEach(function(th) {
     names.push($(th).html());
    });
        
    return names;
  }
  
  function buildCols(data) {
    // Builds cols XML.
    //To do: define widths for each column.
    //Params:
    //  data: row data.
    //Returns:
    //  String of XML formatted column widths.
    
    var cols = '<cols>';
    
    for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
      colNum = i + 1;
      cols += '<col min="' + colNum + '" max="' + colNum + '" width="20" customWidth="1"/>';
    }
    
    cols += '</cols>';
    
    return cols;
  }
  
  function buildRow(data, rowNum, styleNum) {
    // Builds row XML.
    //Params:
    //  data: Row data.
    //  rowNum: Excel row number.
    //  styleNum: style number or empty string for no style.
    //Returns:
    //  String of XML formatted row.
    
    var style = styleNum ? ' s="' + styleNum + '"' : '';
    
    var row = '<row r="' + rowNum + '">';

    for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
      colNum = (i + 10).toString(36).toUpperCase();  // Convert to alpha
      
      var cr = colNum + rowNum;
      
      row += '<c t="inlineStr" r="' + cr + '"' + style + '>' +
              '<is>' +
                '<t>' + data[i] + '</t>' +
              '</is>' +
            '</c>';
    }
      
    row += '</row>';
        
    return row;
  }
  
  function getTableData(table, title) {
    // Processes Datatable row data to build sheet.
    //Params:
    //  table: table ID.
    //  title: Title displayed at top of SS or empty str for no title.
    //Returns:
    //  String of XML formatted worksheet.
    
    var header = getHeaderNames(table);
    var table = $(table).DataTable();
    var rowNum = 1;
    var mergeCells = '';
    var ws = '';
    
    ws += buildCols(header);
    ws += '<sheetData>';
    
    if (title.length > 0) {
      ws += buildRow([title], rowNum, 51);
      rowNum++;
      
      mergeCol = ((header.length - 1) + 10).toString(36).toUpperCase();
      
      mergeCells = '<mergeCells count="1">'+
        '<mergeCell ref="A1:' + mergeCol + '1"/>' +
                   '</mergeCells>';
    }
                      
    ws += buildRow(header, rowNum, 2);
    rowNum++;
    
    // Loop through each row to append to sheet.    
    table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
      var data = this.data();
      
      // If data is object based, then it needs to be converted 
      // to an array before sending to buildRow()
      ws += buildRow(data, rowNum, '');
      
      rowNum++;
    } );
    
    ws += '</sheetData>' + mergeCells;
        
    return ws;

  }
  
  function setSheetName(xlsx, name) {
    // Changes tab title for sheet.
    //Params:
    //  xlsx: xlxs worksheet object.
    //  name: name for sheet.
    
    if (name.length > 0) {
      var source = xlsx.xl['workbook.xml'].getElementsByTagName('sheet')[0];
      source.setAttribute('name', name);
    }
  }
  
  function addSheet(xlsx, table, title, name, sheetId) {
    //Clones sheet from Sheet1 to build new sheet.
    //Params:
    //  xlsx: xlsx object.
    //  table: table ID.
    //  title: Title for top row or blank if no title.
    //  name: Name of new sheet.
    //  sheetId: string containing sheetId for new sheet.
    //Returns:
    //  Updated sheet object.
    
    //Add sheet2 to [Content_Types].xml => <Types>
    //============================================
    var source = xlsx['[Content_Types].xml'].getElementsByTagName('Override')[1];
    var clone = source.cloneNode(true);
    clone.setAttribute('PartName','/xl/worksheets/sheet' + sheetId + '.xml');
    xlsx['[Content_Types].xml'].getElementsByTagName('Types')[0].appendChild(clone);
    
    //Add sheet relationship to xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels => Relationships
    //=====================================================================
    var source = xlsx.xl._rels['workbook.xml.rels'].getElementsByTagName('Relationship')[0];
    var clone = source.cloneNode(true);
    clone.setAttribute('Id','rId'+sheetId+1);
    clone.setAttribute('Target','worksheets/sheet' + sheetId + '.xml');
    xlsx.xl._rels['workbook.xml.rels'].getElementsByTagName('Relationships')[0].appendChild(clone);
    
    //Add second sheet to xl/workbook.xml => <workbook><sheets>
    //=========================================================
    var source = xlsx.xl['workbook.xml'].getElementsByTagName('sheet')[0];
    var clone = source.cloneNode(true);
    clone.setAttribute('name', name);
    clone.setAttribute('sheetId', sheetId);
    clone.setAttribute('r:id','rId'+sheetId+1);
    xlsx.xl['workbook.xml'].getElementsByTagName('sheets')[0].appendChild(clone);
    
    //Add sheet2.xml to xl/worksheets
    //===============================
    var newSheet = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>'+
      '<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" mc:Ignorable="x14ac">'+
      getTableData(table, title) +
      
      '</worksheet>';

    xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet' + sheetId + '.xml'] = $.parseXML(newSheet);
    
  }
  
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bftrip',
    buttons: [
      {
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        text: 'Excel',
        customize: function( xlsx ) {
          setSheetName(xlsx, 'Employees');

          // process additional DataTables in the web page:
          $('table').each(function( index ) {
            if ( index > 0 ) {
              var tableID = '#' + $( this ).attr('id');
              var rowOneTitle = $( this ).attr('data-rowonetitle');
              var sheetName = $( this ).attr('data-sheetname');
              var sheetID = index + 1;
              addSheet(xlsx, tableID, rowOneTitle, sheetName, sheetID);
            }
          });
   
        }
          
      }
    ]

  });
  
  $('#example2').DataTable();  
  $('#example3').DataTable();
  $('#example4').DataTable();
  $('#example5').DataTable();
  $('#example6').DataTable();
    
} );
</script>
```

Comment: what triggers your pdf generation?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen This code is to export table to multiple sheets in a single Excel file. Sorry, I forgot to mention this in my question.